# FreeSWITCH Active Active Callcenter with shared DB

Tags: freeswitch

Has anyone succeeded to use FreeSWITCH Active-Active call center with shared DB ?

In short:  I have 2 FreeSwitch instances, I have joined them MySQL DB, callcenter agents config/statuses is stored in DB. When I register one agent to both of instances, I get error like :

**[ERR] mod_callcenter.c:1566 Member with uuid 5ed4717a-781b-4a6c-8dbe-8b75bc79e187 in queue support@default is gone just before we assigned an agent**

I want to learn whether someone realized this kind of solution and is it possible in general ?

[FS Shared DB error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFsL5.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible yet using mod_callcenter. You can use this setup without mod_callcenter. 
If the active active is not a requirement, you can use both servers active and load mod_callcenter only on one and force all agents to auth using a VIP. If the callcenter server goes down, you migrate the ip for the other server and load the mod_callcenter.